# Display image on same line as div, not underneath it

Tags: html, css, flask

I have a standard flask project in which there are images file under:

```
static/images/thump.png
```

Now I want to display it in this area:

```
<div class="recommendation">results: </div>
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/thumup.png')}}" />
```

But the image isn't displayed at all.

Also, I don't want it to be displayed under div tag, but want it to be displayed after the text:

```
results:
```

How can I do that?

Comment: try removing `static` from the `static/images/thump.png` and one double quote is also missing :( It'd be great if you can put this code in some snippets or codepen

Comment: Yes, Adding the missing double quotes solved the missing problem. Then how to display it right after the text 'results:', instead of the next line? @Uttam

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the div with the text and the image together form a 'recommendation'. In that case this structure might be appropriate:

```
<div class="recommendation">results:<img src="....." /></div>
```

That will more easily allow placing of the text in relation to the image as well as grouping the whole results info together.

Here's an example - a plain snippet which uses flex to position the text mid-point down the image:

```html
<div class="recommendation" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">results:<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFkeW.jpg" /></div>
```